# Adding property to array of object with map and promises

Tags: javascript, object, promise

The assignement of a new property to each object in array, obtained with an async function in map is not working.
Here is my code:

```
asyncFunction.then(array => {
    var promises = array.map(obj => {
      return otherAsyncFunction(obj._id).then(prop => {
        obj.url = prop;
        return obj
      })
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
      console.log(results)
    })
    res.send(user.friends)
})
```

The `console.log(results)` displays the same array.

I've tried to log the new obj juste before the `return obj` and it displays also the old `obj`

Comment: Can't say exactly what's wrong, without exploring your code further. Can you ensure if `url` is a writable property in `obj`, or `obj` is not a frozen object? In non-strict mode, these would fail silently.

Comment: A thing to add is : when I display 'obj.url' just before the return, it displays the good value.

Comment: Do you mean for it to be `asyncFunction().then(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer: the `array` was somehow not mutable, I just copied the initial array with the following:

```
let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
```